# Volume group "vgubuntu" not found. My laptop won’t boot

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, boot

Today, I rebooted my PC (a Dell G5 15) after a update from Ubuntu, you know, the kind of update that pops on the screen and asks you to reboot at the end to complete the update. Well, that’s what I did, and maybe I shouldn’t have.

Now, I got this on my screen. (I have put red marks where I have executed the commands that were recommended above, for this thing to be a little clearer for you.)

[image: Screenshot of the boot messages]

I don’t know what my latest version of Ubuntu that worked was.

I tried to search for similar problems, but I couldn’t find anything that helped me in my case. I tried to select the “Advanced option for Ubuntu” when I hard-restarted my computer, but among the possibilities below, none seems to work.

[image: Screenshot of the boot menu]

How can I fix my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in initramfs type:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 tmpData
```

and next `exit` from initramfs

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1350945/1155712?

For me, it helped... Still, I need to do it every time so still, I'm looking at how to resolve it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please see the [guidelines of writing an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). It's OK to refer to another site, but you should provide the context in your answer. Also this is more a comment than an actual answer to the question. Link-only answers and comments-as-answers will get [deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). It's a good idea to check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439708)